# Rationale behind reuse of "&&"-token for rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I recently held a presentation on C++11, mainly focusing on rvalues and move semantics. During the presentation the question came up on why the standard committee decided to reuse the "&&"-token instead of introducing a new one like "§".

Has anyone came across the rationale for reusing &&?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The committee wanted a token that is on a US keyboard.  We also needed something that would not break existing code.  `&&` seemed like an obvious token to use.  We were also looking for minimal changes to the standard and the idea of reusing a token instead of inventing a new one was attractive.

I credit John Spicer (EDG) with first suggesting `&&` as the token at the April 2002 meeting in Curaçao.

Comment: Note that they could have used the @ symbol which is forbidden in identifiers and not used anywhere in the language.

Comment: Now I'm confused, is § not present on the US layout? BTW: is there any apparent reason why @ is forbidden in identifiers? (considering how one could use a whole lot of characters that are not present on most keyboards...)

Comment: not using a completely new token also has the benefit of not breaking any custom source-code pre-processing that people might use in production.

Comment: @MFH: "Now I'm confused, is § not present on the US layout?" No it isn't. It's also not an ASCII character.

Comment: @PeterT: but those parsers will likely also choke on &&, either they will interpret it as a reference to a reference which is obviously not valid C++03, or they will interpret it as a boolean and, which is not valid either.. i think it is more likely they would ignore a new token like `#` or `$`

Comment: @smerlin: What he meant is that custom preprocessors for C++03 may also work with c++11. Of course a C++03 compiler won't properly compile C++11, but the preprocessing language is independent from the compiler. Preprocessor and compiler are two different programs recognizing different elements in the same code.

Comment: @Morwenn: i know what he meant, i just dont know any preprocessor which uses `$`. My claim that `#` is a new token was obviously wrong, forgot the preprocessor... And know that i think of it there are many extensions which use `#` like OpenMP..